# FullCalendar - Making the day text clickable not the entire cell

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

I am using the uiCalendar

and have added:

```
$scope.dayClick = function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

        //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        //alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
    }
```

This works if I click an empty space in the entire cell, Can I configure this event to only be triggered if I click the on actual day text (i.e. 11)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out

```
$scope.dayClick = function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-day-number')) {
        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

    }
}
```